# i want to remove empty string from a list

Tags: python, list

can someone please tell me why I cant remove the empty string by using following code?

```
numlist = list()

tim = "s x s f f f"
timo = tim.strip()
for line in timo:

    numlist.append(line)

list(filter(None, numlist))

print(numlist)
```

output: `['s', ' ', 'x', ' ', 's', ' ', 'f', ' ', 'f', ' ', 'f']`

desired output: `['s', 'x', 's', 'f', 'f', 'f']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `split` not `strip`. `strip` is for removing leading and trailing characters

```
In [35]: tim = "s x s f f f"

In [36]: tim.split()
Out[36]: ['s', 'x', 's', 'f', 'f', 'f']
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to assign the result of the filtering back to `numlist`, so it made the new `list` and discarded it. Just make the line:

```
numlist = list(filter(None, numlist))
```

That said, it wouldn't have done what you wanted, because a string of a single space is still truthy. If you want to exclude spaces as truthy, a simple tweak would be:

```
numlist = list(filter(str.strip, numlist))
```

Or simplifying further (but with different behavior if the input isn't always single characters with space separation), replace the entirety of your code with just:

```
tim = "s x s f f f"
numlist = tim.split()
print(numlist)
```

as no-arg `split` will split on whitespace, remove leading and trailing whitespace, and return the `list` of non-whitespace components as a single efficient action.

Comment: It's worth noting that `str.split()` will remove *all* whitespace including newlines and tabs, which may not be desirable.

Comment: @SamMorgan: So would the half-assed fix to the `filter` solution (since it's implemented in terms of `strip`, which strips any whitespace). Worth a note, but at least in the OP's case it doesn't seem to matter.